# How can I unit test this async method which (correctly) throws an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

I have the following method in an interface..

```
Task<SearchResult<T>> SearchAsync(TU searchOptions);
```

works great.

Now i'm trying to make a unit test to test when something goes wrong - and the code throws an exception.

In this case, I've setup my method to throw an `HttpRequestException`. My unit test fails to say that I threw that exception ..

```
var result = Should.Throw<HttpRequestException>
    (async () => await service.SearchAsync(searchOptions));
```

the error message from the unit test is

> Shouldly.ChuckedAWobbly
>   var result = Should
>           throw
>       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
>           but does not

So the [assertion framework](http://shouldly.github.io/) is saying: *You've expected an exception, but none was thrown.*

When I step -through- the code, the exception is 100% thrown.

Can anyone see what i've done wrong with my unit test code, please?

Comment: Is the exception by any change caught by something in between?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing async method for specific exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837128/unit-testing-async-method-for-specific-exception)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that your assertion framework does not understand asynchronous methods. I recommend you raise an issue with them.

In the meantime, you can use the [source for `Should.Throw`](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/blob/master/src/Shouldly/ShouldThrowExtensions.cs) to write your own `MyShould.ThrowAsync`:

```
public static async Task<TException> ThrowAsync<TException>(Func<Task> actual)
    where TException : Exception
{
  try
  {
    await actual();
  }
  catch (TException e)
  {
    return e;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new ChuckedAWobbly(new ShouldlyMessage(typeof(TException), e.GetType()).ToString());
  }

  throw new ChuckedAWobbly(new ShouldlyMessage(typeof(TException)).ToString());
}
```

And use it as such:

```
var result = await MyShould.ThrowAsync<HttpRequestException>
    (async () => await service.SearchAsync(searchOptions));
```

or the slightly simpler and equivalent:

```
var result = await MyShould.ThrowAsync<HttpRequestException>
    (() => service.SearchAsync(searchOptions));
```

Comment: FYI the task overloads are in another file since v2 (Feb 2014). https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/blob/master/src/Shouldly/ShouldThrowTaskExtensions.cs#L10

Shouldly does block though so the test doesn't need to await the Should.Throw method. I think we will add Should.ThrowAsync which is asynchronous though

Answer (score 4):

Test it like this:

```
var result = Should.Throw<HttpRequestException>
    (() => service.SearchAsync(searchOptions).Result);
```

Or:

```
var result = Should.Throw<HttpRequestException>
    (() => service.SearchAsync(searchOptions).Wait());
```

Otherwise, your `Should.Throw` returns before the `async` lambda has completed.

Comment: First line doesn't compile.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, it means `Should.Throw` expects a `void` lambda, as far as can tell. The second one does the same, without peeking into the result.

Comment: `Result` and `Wait` both wrap exceptions into an `AggregateException`, so this answer won't work as-is.

Comment: This can also cause a deadlock if there is a synchronization context set here, as you're synchronously blocking on an asynchronous method.

Answer (score 3):

Unit testing async code/functionality is pretty hard. I myself am getting into unit testing async and running into the same problems as you do.

I found the following two resources very helpful:

- [Best practices in async programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) - it delves into the subject of async and the problems with testing it.
- [Unit testing async the wrong way](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html) and [Unit testing async the right way](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html) - delves into the subject, shows the problems that you will encounter and how to setup the testing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the passed lambda returns a Task. The thrown exception can only be observed by `Should.Throw` if it waits for this task to complete, which apparently it does not. As a work-around, you can `.Wait` on the task returned by `SearchAsync` yourself.

`mstest` (the built-in visual studio testing framework) has support for async tests since Visual Studio 2012. You can basically just change the test method declaration by replacing "void" by "async Task".

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException))]
public async Task SomeTest()
{
   await service.SearchAsync(searchOptions);
}
```

You are probably using a different unit testing framework, but it's not clear which one. Consult its documentation to see if it supports async tests.

[NUnit 2.6.3](http://nunit.org/?p=releaseNotes&r=2.6.3) also seems to support async tests.

**edit**: so you are using xUnit. This particular issue was [fixed for xUnit 2.0](https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9799). It's currently still alpha though.

Comment: The passed lambda actually returns `void`, and it's very hard to catch exceptions from `async void` methods. `Wait` wraps its exceptions in `AggregateException`, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown on a different thread to that on which your unit test runs. The unit test framework can only anticipate exceptions on its own thread.

I would suggest you test the exception on a synchronous version of the service.

Comment: So -- are you saying that the `async/await` isn't working and the exception is not coming through and I can't test for this thing?

Comment: But .. there is no sync method.

Comment: No, that is normal behaviour. This may give some context on exception handling for async tasks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Today Shouldly contains `Should.ThrowAsync<T>`.

You can use it like this:

```
await Should.ThrowAsync<HttpRequestException>(() => service.SearchAsync(searchOptions));
```