# My unit test is not catching an exception within my controller action

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

I have a unit test, something like:

```
[Test]
public void ThingController__Put__when_thing_is_invalid__then__throws()
{
    var controller = this.CreateThingController();

    try
    {
        var r = controller.Put("thing1", this.CreateInvalidThing());
    }
    catch(HttpResponseException hrex) when (hrex.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        return; // implicit pass.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail($"Wrong exception {ex.GetType().Name}");
    }

    Assert.Fail("No exception thrown!");
}
```

But it always hits the last `Fail`, i.e. no exception is thrown. I have turned on first chance exceptions and can see it being thrown and is rethrown all the way up. It definitely is bubbling all the way up.

Note: SO flagged this as a possible duplicate of

[Unit testing async method for specific exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837128/unit-testing-async-method-for-specific-exception)

That question is a how-to but this one is a problem-solution, specifically for why a `catch` is not being hit, i.e. you know how, but made a common mistake forgetting that the action is async - because they normally don't have `Async` suffix - and needs unwrapping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing async method for specific exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837128/unit-testing-async-method-for-specific-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Put method is an async Task method, which I suspect it is based on the issue you're describing you can modify your test method to appropriately handle async/await by making the signature async Task. If your Put method is async task, it is executing as a hot task but since it is not being awaited currently your unit test thread continues on before your exception is actually raised. Essentially the original code is creating a fire and forget scenario.

```
[Test]
public async Task ThingController__Put__when_thing_is_invalid__then__throws()
{
    var controller = this.CreateThingController();

    try
    {
        var r = await controller.Put("thing1", this.CreateInvalidThing());
    }
    catch(HttpResponseException hrex) when (hrex.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        return; // implicit pass.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail($"Wrong exception {ex.GetType().Name}");
    }

    Assert.Fail("No exception thrown!");
}
```

Comment: Note: recent testing frameworks support this but if working on an old project you may still need to check your version.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Put` action method asynchronous?

If so, then you are not accessing the result of the action and the exception is not being 'unwrapped'.

You should either be calling `r.ExecuteAsync(...)` if its an `IHttpActionResult`, or adding `r.Wait();` under the call to `Put(...)`.

You may also need to alter your catch block to catch `AggregateException` and inspect it.

Comment: Instead of `r.Wait()`, you should make the unit test `async` and use `await r`. Then you won't have to deal with `AggregateException`.

Comment: Can't disagree with that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191831/how-do-i-test-an-async-method-with-nunit-eventually-with-another-framework